# input value is not accepting this.state.term

Tags: reactjs, variable-assignment

Everything is working just fine if i don't include `value = {this.state.term}` in my input.

value is not accepting `this.state.term`

```
class SearchBar extends React.Component {

State = {term : ''};
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <form>
                <div className="ui icon input">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." 
                    value = {this.state.term}
                    onChange={e => this.setState({term : e.target.value}) } />
                    <i className="search icon"></i>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
            );
        }
    }
```

***Error***

TypeError: Cannot read property 'term' of null

Comment: i apologize for so unprofessional words used.. just a beginner

Answer (score 1):

You need to put state in the right place,

A) if it's a component, then you need to put it in constructor

```
  class xxx extends ... {
    constructor(props) { this.state = { terms: xxx } }
    render() { ... }
```

B) if it's a function, then you put it inside function via hooks

```
   const xxx = () => {
     const [terms] = useState(xxx)
     return (...)
   }
```

But you can't mix them, because `state` isn't a global variable. It's actually a local variable which follows the component cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Please specify the state with a small s like:

```
state = { term: '' };
```